# Executing multiple bash statements simultaneously including airodump-ng

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

On my Raspberry Pi I want to execute some code everytime the the pi boots. So I add the following line to /etc/rc.local

```
/home/pi/Documents/start.sh &
```

in that file I have the following code:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 &
sudo airodump-ng --write output mon0 &
python3 start_server.py output01.csv &
```

Note that all the lines are processed in a seperate subprocess by using the ampersand symbol. Unfortnately this doesn't work. When executing the first line I see all the output and then after it terminates the second line is executed, and all the output is shown. Since this process never ends, the process never terminates and the third statement is not executed.

What is going wrong here, why aren't the statements executed in subprocesses?
[And yes, I'm sure the code is correct since it works perfectly when running line 1-2 in one terminal and 3 in another terminal]

Comment: The commands look like they depend on each other. Would you expect the script to work if you reversed the order of the three commands? If not, you can't expect them to work as separate subprocesses started at the same time.

Comment: I'd try muting the output ```airodump-ng``` might produce like so ```sudo sh -c 'airodump-ng --write output mon0 2>&1 >/dev/null' &```

Answer (score 0):

I would add "nohup".

```
nohup sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 &
nohup sudo airodump-ng --write output mon0 &
nohup python3 start_server.py output01.csv &
```